# Rename all Files and Folders - The Movie - Movie, The

Tags: command-line, rename

I'm looking for a way to clean up my naming convention in my media folder.

For instance rename

```
The Thing (1982)
|_ The Thing (1982).mkv
```

to:

```
Thing, The (1982)
|_ Thing, The (1982).mkv
```

I've found lots of messages and scripts to rename based on patterns, or folder names, but not something this basic and specific.

Basically, Plex sorts 'The' movies and shows correctly, but Emby sorts the shows and movies based on the file/folder naming format. Thus I would like to correct my naming convention.

Can anyone assist with this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out FileBot at https://www.filebot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3709&p=32848#p32848 or https://www.filebot.net/ or the Ubuntu Software store. It provides a nice way to bulk rename video files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just one way to approach the problem with Perl [`rename` [image: Install rename]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/rename):

```bsh
rename -n 's/The ([^(]*) /$1, The /'
```

This saves the name without the leading “The ” as group 1 and replaces this part of the name with group 1 followed by “, The”.
As you want to rename directories as well as the files in them you need to do the renaming in two steps, the directories first and the files after them. With the `-n` option, `rename` just prints the names of files to be renamed without actually performing – that's great for testing.

#### Example run

```bsh
$ tree -A --noreport
.
└── The\ Thing\ (1982)
    └── The\ Thing\ (1982).mkv
$ rename -n 's/The ([^(]*) /$1, The /' */ # */ matches every directory
rename(The Thing (1982)/, Thing, The (1982)/) # old and new name appear in the brackets, separated by comma
$ rename 's/The ([^(]*) /$1, The /' */ # let's go!
$ tree -A --noreport # dirs are done, now to the files!
.
└── Thing,\ The\ (1982)
    └── The\ Thing\ (1982).mkv
$ rename -n 's/The ([^(]*) /$1, The /' */* # */* matches every file in a subdirectory
rename(Thing, The (1982)/The Thing (1982).mkv, Thing, The (1982)/Thing, The (1982).mkv)
$ rename 's/The ([^(]*) /$1, The /' */*
$ tree -A --noreport
.
└── Thing,\ The\ (1982)
    └── Thing,\ The\ (1982).mkv
```

You can of course leave out the `-n` step, but better safe than sorry.